# The first time the night mode code is executed, it will trigger the current reboot

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-night-mode

The first time the **Night Mode** code is executed, it restarts the Activity

The second time, the code will work correctly and make changes to the program

I used the following code:

```java
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new CheckedNightMode().execute();

    }
    private class CheckedNightMode extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Night_Mode", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            boolean state = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("State", false);
            if (state) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            } else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            checkLanguage();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, Main.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }, 3000);
        }

        private void checkLanguage() {
            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Language", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String checkedLanguage = sharedpreferences.getString("Select", "en");
            setLanguageState(checkedLanguage);
        }

        private void setLanguageState(String language) {
            Resources resources = getResources();
            Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
            configuration.setLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag(language));
            resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, displayMetrics);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Styles.xml:

```xml
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorRed</item>
    </style>
```

With the theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` I tried, but it was still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code is correct. Google's own document states that if you want to change the theme at runtime, the current action will be restarted.

> **Note**: Starting with AppCompat v1.1.0, setDefaultNightMode() automatically recreates any started activities.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour. Since resources are changed, android:configChanges is defaulting to restarting the activity. Read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes to understand. Essentially, you are encountering the expected behaviour, not a bug, and you probably should restart the activity, otherwise you will have to reinstantiate/reconfigure each view recursively and it will be complicated and buggy.